# PT9 & Complete Production Upgrade Questions

Tags: pro-tools, dvtoolkit

First order of business:

I have Pro Tools LE 7.4 and DV Toolkit 2

From what I understand I can upgrade LE to PT9 for $250

I can also upgrade my DV Toolkit to Complete Production Toolkit for $300

Let me know if this is correct.

---

Second:

PT9 comes with DV Toolkit 2 - does this mean I could sell my old DV Toolkit license and upgrade the one that comes with PT9 for $300?

---

Thanks all!

-C3Sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upgrade to the CPTK 2 for $300, you'll need to surrender your DVTK 2 license. If you sell the license and want to but the CPTK 2 aftwerwards, you'll have to pay the full $2K for it.

So, even if you're only considering the CPTK 2, I'd suggest holding onto that license.

Comment: @Shaun Right, I would assume you would have to give up the DV Toolkit license. So what I am gathering from your post is that the DV Toolkit included in PT9 is a built in feature of PT9 and not an actual license for DV Toolkit.  If PT9 ships with an actual license of DVToolkit, then I wouldnt see why not to sell the old one. 

Comment: @C3Sound - Yeah, the DVToolkit functionality is included in 9, there is no license. It's merely an issue of upgrading to CPTK from other toolkits that people alredy own. Since the functionality is included, and people who own DVTK already shelled out a bunch of dough for it, the CPTK upgrade is only $300. If you sell your license DVTK, and want to add the CPTK in the future, you're gonna be out more money.

Comment: Then its common sense not to sell the license.

Comment: @C3Sound - that would be my suggestion ;)

Comment: @Shaun Heres a sub question - is there a point in getting complete production toolkit if you have a 003? Meaning - one of the selling points of CPTK is 5.1 or 7.1 panning - do you know if using the optical port of the 003 would output to a surround system? If so, another question being - Can you set the outputs of the center and surround speakers to optical and left and right to analog (I would like to use my studio monitors for left and right)? Or would this cause a delay issue with combining optical and analog?

Comment: @C3Sound - Theoretically thats possible, but I can't speak to delay/latency issues in that scenario. I'd be more concerned with session sample rates in that scenario, as the optical can't handle anything above 48kHz. Personally, I would just send everything out the balanced outputs. There's nothing in the system that REQUIRES to use the "Main Outs." The one thing you won't be able to take advantage of with the 003, and this is why I'll probably sell my 002 eventually, is the 192kHz sample rate.

Comment: @Shaun Well, LE is really just 96k editing at max anyways right - so 192k is not an issue when talkin LE. And in post-production most everything is handed over at 48k anyways right - so setting the SR at 48 and then just import converting audio to session SR is what I do currently with 96 or 192 sound. So if session is at 48k the optical setup i mentioned should be fine, like you said theoretically. Let me email you this specific setup, its some rigging, but I think it will be fine. Thanks for your help and interest - I greatly appreciate your knowledge.

Comment: @C3Sound - True, but PT9 with CPTK is capable of 192kHz. Remember, it's not LE anymore. Personally, I always work at the highest resolution I can, mainly for cleaner audio processing with plug-ins, and then bounce to deliverable bit/samplerate. My session will definitely be in 96 if more than half of my files are, but I won't jump up to 192 if I only have a few files in that sample rate. Personally, I'm not a fan of mixing output formats within a single sound field when monitoring. That's introducing more variables than I like to have. e-mail's spfarley [at] gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Im literally in the same situation. I prices for upgrade is right but I think you will need your dv toolkit license to upgrade to complete toolkit.